# Deserialized Json Results in Null List in Target Type

Tags: c#, json.net

When I attempt to deserialize the following JSON using Newtonsoft JSON, the target type to which I am deserializing always returns null for a List property "FoodPositions". The other properties of that class do not return null:

JSON sample:   `{"baxterPosition":"2x5","baxterFoodLevel":18,"mousePosition":"5x0","mouseFoodLevel":18,"foodPositions":["0x0","5x5"],"totalRounds":2,"gameComplete":false}`

Here is the class I am deserializing to:

```
 class BaxterResult
    {
        [JsonProperty("baxterPosition")]
        public string BaxterPosition { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("baxterFoodLevel")]
        public int BaxterFoodLevel { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("mousePosition")]
        public string MousePosition { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("mouseFoodLevel")]
        public int MouseFoodLevel { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("foodPositions")]
        public List<string> FoodPositions { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("totalRounds")]
        public int TotalRounds { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("gameComplete")]
        public bool GameComplete { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the call to deserialize:

```
BaxterResult BaxterLocal = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BaxterResult>(reader.ReadToEnd());
```

Comment: Save this into a variable and make sure it has what you expect: `reader.ReadToEnd()`. Maybe it has no `foodPositions`

Comment: Cannot reproduce with the example provided. See [here](http://rextester.com/TATN55407)

Comment: This is not an answer to the original question, but you should know you should store `FoodPositions` as `List<Point>` instead of `List<string>`, because it's type-safe. Saving numbers as strings will sooner or later fail you.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I went ahead and converted to points. @john I used the adjusted code with points in the rextester you provided and got the desired result. I then took the same code and used it in my app and the FoodPositions is null. There must be something in my environment that is causing this. Will keep digging.

Answer (score 1):

After further testing, I determined that the issue was actually a bug in the Visual Studio debugger when working with Xamarin Forms and Xamarin Live. The List FoodPositions was actually populated. See [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/119749/newtonsoft-json-serializeobject-and-deserializeobject-returning-null). Thanks to all for their feedback- the way I found out it was populated was by adding a foreach to enumerate the List and I saw that it iterated the proper number of times.